# javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException on empty long value

Tags: jsf, websphere

I have application developed in JSF 1.2 / Rich Faces 3.3 / Tomcat 6 / Java 1.6. In a page i have a textbox for entering a long value. if i leave the text box empty and check its value in bean as follows:-

```
  if(this.employeeAge.toString() == "" || this.employeeAge == null ||    
  this.employeeAge  == 0)  // this is code line no 809 generating error
  { System.out.println("employee age not entered");
  }
```

snippet from jsp page is as follow:-

```
   <h:outputText value="Employee Age" />
   <h:inputText value="#{employeeBean.employeeAge}" id="empAge" maxlength="3"  />
```

This works with apache tomcat but on Web Sphere, I get following error

```
        [12/16/14 12:22:10:641 PKT] 00000037 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[Faces Servlet]: javax
    .faces.FacesException: #{employeeBean.save}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:387)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxActionComponent.broadcast(AjaxActionComponent.java:55)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:324)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:299)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:256)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:469)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at restricted.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:162)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3826)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:445)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:301)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1563)
    Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 44 more
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mtech.beans.EmployeeBean.save(EmployeeBean.java:809)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:159)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JspMethodExpression.invoke(JspMethodExpression.java:67)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 45 more
```

What is needed to be done to avoid this error.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(this.employeeAge.toString() == "" || this.employeeAge == null ||    
  this.employeeAge  == 0)  // this is code line no 809 generating erro
```

You are first using `employeeAge` value (for `toString()`), and *after* you are checking if it is `null`.

In an `if`, expressions are evaluated in order. Also, they are short-circuited (if you have an `||` and the left expression is `true`, the right expression is not evaluated because `true || anything -> true`.

Just change the order

```
if (this.employeeAge == null || this.employeeAge.toString() == "" ||    
  this.employeeAge  == 0)  // this is code line no 809 generating erro
```

In case `employeeAge` is null, the first expression will return `true` and none of the other will be evaluated.

Comment: Oh, and of course it has nothing to do with EL. It is just that the bad code is called after evaluating an expression, but the expression itself is not the issue.

Comment: `this.employeeAge.toString() == ""`?

Comment: While not what is causing your issue, @Tiny's comment is also valid, you should not use `==` to compare objects for equality (in this case, it would be better `this.employeeAge.toString().length() == 0`)